# Prevent CKEditor 4 from loading config.js for bundling and minification

Tags: ckeditor, bundling-and-minification

We are creating a build process to minify and concatenate all our files.

Unfortunately, CKEditor loads `config.js` and `styles.js` by itself. I would like to concatenate all of these files together so that there's only 1 http request.

As a test, I tried to create a file that contains `ckeditor.js` and `config.js` combined together using the files from the `basic` download.

Unfortunately, it seems that `ckeditor` will still go ahead and try to load a `config.js`.

However, if I use the `ckeditor.js` hosted by ckeditor, there appears to only be 1 request: http://jsfiddle.net/jdPn3/

In the above case, `config.js` and `styles.js` does not appear to be loaded.

How are they doing the concatenation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some reason, `CKEDITOR.editorConfig()` is not called once CKEditor is loaded. I think it is only called when instantiating an editor.

Therefore, I had to modify the global configuration directly:

```
CKEDITOR.config.customConfig = false; //no config.js
CKEDITOR.config.stylesSet = false; //no styles.js
CKEDITOR.config.defaultLanguage = 'en'; //default language
CKEDITOR.config.language = 'en'; //ui language
```

Comment: Yes, the `CKEDITOR.editorConfig` is called every time editor is being initialized. You can disable loading `config.js` (and calling that function) by setting the `config.customConfig` option globally (as you did) or by passing it to `CKEDITOR.replace()` or other method you use to initialize CKEditor.